# Comparing more than 2 fields in Access query

Tags: ms-access

In an Access query, if I want to compare 2 fields, I do something like :-

```
IIf([Field1] = [Field2], "Yes", "No") AS [MATCH]
```

Is it possible to compare 3 fields, and if all the 3 values are different then result should be Yes, otherwise the result should be No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any 2 of the 3 fields are equal, you want the result to be `"No"`.
So use the OR operator:

```
IIf(
  [Field1] = [Field2] OR [Field1] = [Field3] OR [Field2] = [Field3], 
  "No", 
  "Yes"
) AS [MATCH]
```

Answer (score 1):

GoodJuJus answer is almost there.

IIf(([Field1]=[Field2] AND [Field2]=[Field3] AND [Field1]=[Field3]),"No","Yes") AS [MATCH]
This will allow only cases where all three fields are different.

If you want to accept cases with 2 (but not 3) identical values this will not work.

Anyway inverting the logic might make it nicer to read:

IIf(([Field1]<>[Field2] And [Field2]<>[Field3] And [Field1]<>[Field3]),"Yes","No") AS [MATCH]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just expand your logic with the logical AND operator:

```
IIf(([Field1]=[Field2] And [Field2]=[Field3]),"Yes","No") AS [MATCH]
```

Note though that in your question you said, 'if all the 3 values are different then result should be Yes, otherwise the result should be No'.  This contradicts your SQL query that has 'Yes' where the values are equal.  Switch your "Y","N" around to suit....

This will return:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|Field1 |Field2 |Field3 |Result |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|1234   |1234   |1234   |Y      |
|1234   |aabb   |aabb   |N      |   
|1234   |we     |1234   |N      |
|-------------------------------|
```

Comment: Using this brings back Yes if all 3 values the same. If I swap the Yes/No positions from your code and filter by Yes, there can be equal values in Field 1 and 3.

Comment: In my example the query will only ever return "Yes" if all 3 values are equal, everything else will return "No".  I thought this was the behaviour you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways to do it:

In my examples, I have it set to "yes" if there's a match, so you may have to tweak it. I'm unsure if you really want it to say "yes" if it's not a match.

**Using the Macro Builder**

[image: Using the Macro Builder]

**In case you want to use VBA:**

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()
If Text1.Value = Text2.Value Then
step1 = "yes"
End If

If Text1.Value <> Text2.Value Then
step1 = "no"
End If


If Text1.Value = Text3.Value Then
step2 = "yes"
End If

If Text1.Value <> Text3.Value Then
step1 = "no"
End If


If step1 = step2 Then
Label25.Caption = "yes"
End If

If step1 <> step2 Then
Label25.Caption = "no"
End If
```